# Fetching complete HTML page (including AJAX responses) in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, delay

I am trying to crawl an e-commerce catalogue, where products data is loaded using Ajax responses.

Thus, the content in response using get request is incomplete (partial data).

I am using Ruby's default HTTP library for fetching & `Nokogiri` for parsing.

Is there any way, in which I can initiate a request & record the response after some delay ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a libary/method/way which has a javascript engine to execute javascript since ajax is used (if you want to have it done automatically).

You could use a headless browser for this like phantomjs:

[PhantomJS Project Homepage](http://phantomjs.org/)

[PhantomJS for Ruby](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem)

[Wiki Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS)

It's basically a normal browser without a frontend. 
PhantomJS uses the Webkit Engine (e.g. used by Safari).
So it's capable of executing JS and therefor also AJAX.

Comment: Its not fully true. If you know enough beforehand you can usually execute the request without javascript involved.

Comment: @Felix: I agree (edited the answer).
But it can be a lot of work (and headache) to custom build all the AJAX request, to have at the end the same DOM as normally with a webbrowser.
And, as you mentioned, you need to know enough beforehand. While it's okay for doing this for just one specific "page", it can take ages to do this for different sites / pages of a site.

Comment: absolutely agreed.